# How to use Tasword 2 with Esxdos

Tags: zx-spectrum, divmmc, sd-card

I'd like to be use the Tasword 2 text editor for the ZX Spectrum to load and save text files on an SD card. Gary Lancaster provides a [version of Tasword](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/zxplus3e/software.html#tasword) that uses Residos system calls, but as far as I know it's hard to get residos to work with FAT32 formatted partitions. Also, I only have a DivMMC device that
has Esxdos on it.

The [Tasword user manual](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/pub/sinclair/games-info/t/TaswordTwo.pdf) has a section on how to customise the program to use it with microdrives and mentions it can also be customised for other disk interfaces, but I don't know how to start with this process to make it work with Esxdos.

Maybe someone has done this customisation already and could share their code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the Tasword manual is actually a good starting point. Type in/change as per the manual.

Then (or, rather do that when you apply the changes as per the manual, you don't need to change any lines that are not mentioned in the manual's microdrive conversion chapter) change the following:

1. Wherever you find a line that contains

   ```
   LOAD *"m";1;"<filename>"
   ```

   (filename can either be a string variable or literal in quotes) change that line to read

   ```
   LOAD *;"<filename>"
   ```

   (that would practically only appear in the lines you changed according to the manual. You should also change all occurrences of "SAVE" and "VERIFY" accordingly, these lines look very similar.)
2. Change all occurrences of "CAT something" to "CAT *"

Proceed according to the manual to save Tasword to disk (RUN, then STOP, then "t" and ENTER). You might be prompted with a "File exists, overwrite?" prompt, answer with pressing "Y"

Some examples:
Line 700 should read

```
    CLS : LET a$="tasword": SAVE "*";"run" LINE 15
```

Line 780 should read

```
    VERIFY *; "run" : PRINT AT 21,0;"Tasword basic O.K.";AT 19,0;
```

or, accordingly, line 1000 should read

```
    LET b=FN p(62216): CLS : CAT *
```

Most esx-enabled ZX Spectrums won't have more than one drive, so changing the drive number from the program doesn't make much sense. The program will, if changed as above, save all text files to the current directory (i.e. the directory that holds the Tasword program). If you don't like this, you need to allow for that (build a prompt and input), but that's a bigger change.